# Samsung mobile default browser AngularJS $http POST request failing

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, samsung-mobile

I have a web app that has a simple form submission. The app is created using AngularJS and uses $http for all HTTP requests such as GET and POST. 
The app works fines for all browsers (Chrome/Firefox/Safari) on pc/laptop as well as iOS tablets and phones (iPad and iPhone - Safari and Chrome).

I've also tested the app on Android devices and Google Nexus phone and tablet (Chrome and Firefox) works fine as well.

On Samsung Galaxy S3 the app works as intended on Chrome and Firefox AND the Samsung default browser.

**However, using the default/stock browser on Samsung mobile devices (specifically Samsung Galaxy S4 and Samsung Galaxy Tab 3), the GET request works fine (returns with status 202) but the POST request fails with status 0.**

The POST request never makes it to the server and because the response is immediate, it leads me to believe that the response produced by the Samsung Default Browser itself.

I'm using the standard AngularJS $http resource and calling $save to activate the POST request. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

There is no easy way to inspect the Samsung default browser (unlike Chrome inspector using USB) so I've added an alert in an error case using `alert(angular.toJson(e));` and the stringified response I get upon POST request looks like this:

```
{"data":"","status":"0","config":"{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"https://server-url.com","data":{submission data}}}
```

I thought perhaps the issue is with submission data itself so I've submitted an empty object as a submission data but the response is the same.

I've seen several posts on the web regarding issues with Samsung default browser but have not been able to find any resource that relates to the issue at hand.

Does anyone have any experience with the Samsung default browser with web apps built with AngularJS?

Chrome emulator is not useful here because the emulator can't mimic the same error since it uses it's own JS engine.